# Can we create a FxCop Custom Rule to check for Comments Ratio in a class file using C#

Tags: c#, fxcop

I know that FxCOP Custom Rules work on IL Code. Also have already created a custom rule to check the number of input parameters for a method. Now, I want to know whether we can create Custom Rule to implement Comments Ratio (i.e 1:15) in a class file. Kindly let me know your views.

Comment: Do you understand what "FxCOP Custom Rules work on IL Code" means?

Answer (score 8):

Since FxCop only sees the compiled IL, it can't really make judgement calls on something that is really only available in the source. If you want to do something with the source code itself, you'll need to use a checker that operates on that level.

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) or possibly [Roslyn CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) would be candidates to implement your rule. A custom plugin for [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/plugins/) or [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/coderush_extensibility.xml) could also work.

NDepend ships with this functionality as Patrick points out.

Answer (score 1):

FxCop doesn't parses (C#) source files it only focuses its analysis on IL compiled code. Hence FxCop has no idea about the comment in source file.

---

Alternatively, you can use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for writing a custom code rule to check **Comments Ratio in a class file using C#** (*Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the tool*).

NDepend is a IL static analyzer, that also parses C# source files to gather comments code metric (more details on this here: [Understanding NDepend Analysis Inputs](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Inputs.aspx) ).

Also NDepend let's query the code through C# LINQ queries, and a query can become a rule when prefixed with  `warnif count > XX`. As a consequence, writing a LINQ code rule for checking *Comments Ratio in a class file using C#* can be as easy as writing:

```
// <Name>Types not enough commented</Name>
warnif count > 0
from t in Application.Types
where t.NbLinesOfCode > 0 
let commentRatio = t.NbLinesOfComment / (float)t.NbLinesOfCode
where commentRatio < 0.5 // Require at least 50% of comments
orderby commentRatio descending
select new { t, 
             commentRatio , 
             t.NbLinesOfComment, 
             t.NbLinesOfCode 
           }
```

This code rule can be edited and executed live in Visual Studio, and the types set result presentation comes with facilities to group by assemblies/namespaces, and to jump to type definition in source code:

[image: Ratio Comment CQLinq NDepend]

Such code rule [can be checked live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx), and [at Build process time](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule) when a [HTML+JS report](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) can be created. Also, around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are provided.